# I listen the data from socket.When I receive the data, I update the array like this .but state is not updated.Please help me and thanks in advance

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

```js
socket?.on('addLocation', data => {
  console.log('addLocation', data);
  let isFound = false;
  let newMarkers = markers.map(marker => {
    if (marker.fleet_id == data.fleetId) {
      isFound = false;
      return {
        ...marker,
        latitude: data.lat,
        longitude: data.long,
      };
    } else {
      return marker;
    }
  });

  if (!isFound) {
    newMarkers = [
      ...newMarkers,
      {
        fleet_id: data.fleetId,
        latitude: data.lat,
        longitude: data.long,
      },
    ];
  }
  setMarker(newMarkers);
})
```

Comment: Is `markers` the state that `setMarker` is updating?

Comment: @DrewReese Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
socket?.on('addLocation', ({ fleetId, lat, long }) => {
  setMarkers(existing => {
    const latLng = { latitude: lat, longitude: long };
    const index = existing.findIndex(m => m.fleet_id === fleetId);
    if (index === -1) {
      return [...existing, {
        fleet_id: fleetId,
        ...latLng
      }]
    } else {
      const clone = [...existing];
      clone[index] = {
        ...clone[index],
        ...latLng
      }
      return clone;
    }
  });
});
```

There are a few things here:

1. You should use the callback flavour of `setMarkers` to ensure you have the "latest" copy when you're modifying it.
2. The code as written is pretty convoluted, you can simplify it a lot. `isFound` will always be false is also a logic issue.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `markers` the state that `setMarker` is updating then this appears to be an issue of a stale enclosure over the `markers` state. The callback is updating the closed over state and not the current `markers` state value.

Use a functional state update to correctly access the previous state instead of the stale value. `Array.prototype.map` is meant to map one set of values to another, and shouldn't have side-effects like setting an `isFound` flag. Search the data first to decide if the state needs to be updated or if a new element needs to be appended.

Example:

```
socket?.on('addLocation', data => {
  console.log('addLocation', data);
  setMarker(markers => {
    const isFound = markers.some(marker => marker.fleet_id == data.fleetId);

    if (isFound) {
      return markers.map(marker => marker.fleet_id == data.fleetId
        ? {
          ...marker,
          latitude: data.lat,
          longitude: data.long,
        }
        : marker
      );
    }

    return [
      ...markers,
      {
        fleet_id: data.fleetId,
        latitude: data.lat,
        longitude: data.long,
      },
    ];
  });
});
```